# Hyperlink to particular Text in a cell on the same sheet

Tags: hyperlink, excel-2010

I'm working with Excel 2010. What I'm trying to accomplish is creating a hyperlink which finds a cell containing some specific text, and simply brings the user to that cell. It would be simple if the cell stayed in the same position in the column, but more data is always being added to that column, and the cell location which contains the text keeps changing.

Although I've seen several articles that I *suspect* might address the problem, they were so involved that I couldn't be certain they were what I was looking for, since I've been away from this for years, and am relearning it all from scratch.

Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

Say we want to go to *"treasure"* in column **D**:

```
=HYPERLINK("#d" & MATCH("treasure",D:D,0),"jump to treasure")
```

[image]

This can be modified if you did not know which column to search!